# Visual Website Optimizer and Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

We are trying to integrate visual website optimizer into a site of ours that uses Code Igniter.

The problem is when we go into the VWO control panel to look at stats and previews nothing seems to be working. In the previews panel, all of them come up as code igniter error pages that say "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

I have researched some solutions to this and have tried changing the regex in system/config to allow more characters, all characters etc and I am still having the problem.

Any known issues or problems trying to integrate VWO and Code Igniter? This definitely seems to be a url issue but I can't nail it down.

Comment: I am an engineer at VWO. Can you please provide more details about the same on our support (like your account details and test names) so that we can check and provide a solution at the earliest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the reason that the website is not accepting the Query parameter after "?" required to generate previews. To resolve the issue, please take the direct preview link and replace the "?" with "#" and then the previews will load fine.